# Syntax Highlighting in VS2013 for MicroTemplating

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, syntax-highlighting, template-engine

I am working on a project that uses client template rendering. I decided to use Micro-Templating engine.

The problem is syntax highlighting feature of VS2013 corrupts my template codes. Other template engines, such as JSRender, can be recognised and highlighted well by Visual Studio Editor.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jjt9g.png

As you see, JSRender template highlighted well but VS didn't recognise my MicroTemplating template. I copied this template example from http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/

How can I make VS to recognise MicroTemplating templates like JSRender? If there is not any option, can highlighting and automatic code fixing features of VS be disabled?

Thanks for your replies in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have a script block marked as type=html which causes the HTML editor/language service to come in to play within the block.  There’s no way to turn off the HTML editor inside  blocks marked type=”text/html”.

You could turn off HTML validation in Tools -> Options, but that only solves the warnings (e.g. green squiggles, Error List items).  There's no way to control the formatting/highlighting.

If this is something you'd like to see made available in a future update to the HTML language support in VS, you should log a request at http://visualstudio.uservoice.com so that others can vote on it and increase the likelihood that it will get picked up.